# Returning the nth value using index or vlookup?

Tags: excel

Let's say I have a spreadsheet of fruits with randomly assigned values.

```
Banana - 7
Apple - 0
Banana - 1
Strawberry - 4
Banana - 3
Strawberry - 2
```

How would I, in a separate spreadsheet return the values of these fruits if I only had a list of the fruits? Is there a way to rule out say Banana - 7, once I've iterated through it once and then the next time I run into Banana I can return 1?

```
Banana - ?
Apple - ?
Banana - ?
Strawberry -?
Banana -?
Strawberry - ?
```

Trying to work with something like this but I'm not sure.

https://exceljet.net/formula/get-nth-match-with-index-match

For clarity I have to return the full list, I cannot parse out just the bananas. I am thinking I will need a help column using countif and small in the main function but I'm having troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use AGGREGATE to return the nth row number:

```
=INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($A$1:$A$6)/($A$1:$A$6=E1),COUNTIF($E$1:$E1,E1)))
```

[image]

---

To show that the order does not matter in the second list:

[image]

Comment: Thanks this puts me on the right track for sure, upvoted. I think I can take it from here, much appreciated.